# Jenkins cannot build maven with [0.0.1,)

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I'm trying to run the build of a project, which has as dependence, a jar of my own.

Code dependency:

```
<profile>
            <id>local-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>ambient</name>
                    <value>local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.enterprise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>enterpriseUtil</artifactId>
                    <version>[0.0.1,)</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>${finalName}</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources_local</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-war-plugin-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
                        <configuration>
                            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                            <warSourceExcludes>META-INF/context.xml</warSourceExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

The strangest thing is that a local build succeeds, even if I exclude the dependency from my .m2, and download from my nexus

The error:

```
No versions available for com.enterprise:enterpriseUtil:jar:[0.0.1,) within specified range -> [Help 1]
```